# Combine external JavaScript best practice

Tags: javascript, php

I was making an audit to my website and found out this message about
combining external javascripts into one.

My doubt is if it would be a good practice to do something like this:

```
function js($which) {

    $output = "";

    switch($which) {

        case "mainsec1";
            $output .= file_get_contents("js/main.js");
            $output .= file_get_contents("js/sec1.js");
        break;

    }

    // And so on with the other cases

    echo $output;
}
```

then from the html i would do something like:

```
 <script src="controller/js/mainsec1"></script>
```

That way i can reduce the amount of http request, but still can preserve different files for maintenance issues avoiding redundancy.

What do you think?

Comment: This is called concatenating and it is one of the methods developers can use to reduce load times and the need for concurrent downloading of resources.

Comment: Add js minification into your **deployment** cycle, eg upload minified, but maintain seperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

Here what you should do is to combine all your JavaScript to a single file. To do that please refer the following link.

[Combine JavaScript & CSS.](http://rakaz.nl/code/combine)

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with that approach making setting appropriate cache control headers and performing HTTP compression more complicated then it needs to be.

It would be simpler and more efficient to do concatenation at build time instead of at run time.

Comment: but in that case i should do every combination of js concatenation for each section of the website isnt it?

Comment: Common JS should not be concatenated with specific JS for each page. That just reloads the common JS instead of caching it. Either have a common.js and a page-specific.js file for each page, or just load all the page specific code up front.

Comment: yes but what about js plugins, you have a specific js for lets say category1 , but category1 also uses 3 jquery plugins, which most of the other categories doesnt use. what would be the correct practice?

Comment: See my previous comment. Either include the plugins in the one common.js, or bundle them up and load them in second script element on the pages that use them.